# Multiple lines one side of equation with a Curly Bracket

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I am trying to write an equation that looks like this, everything should be left aligned on the right hand side.

[image]

I am using the following code to write this equation.

```
  \begin{equation}
  D_{it} = \Bigg\{if \ bank \ i \ issues \ ABS \ at \ time \ t \\
  2 \ if \ bank \ i \ issue \ CBs \ at \ time \ t \\ 
  \ 0 \ otherwise
  \end{equation}
```

I am putting `\\` for a new line but it does not work. Please guide how I can write the desired equation.

Comment: You are looking for the `cases` environment of the `amsmath` package.  Also the `\text{}` macro for setting text inside math mode.

Answer (score 122):

Use the `cases` environment, like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  D_{it} =
    \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if bank $i$ issues ABs at time $t$}\\
      2 & \text{if bank $i$ issues CBs at time $t$}\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: However, this equation is not numbered by following this method. How I can number it?

Comment: @AhmedArif Remove the star after `equation`.

Comment: Note this works also in MathJax :-) :-)

Comment: @Antonello Great, good to know ...

Comment: how can i close the bracket?

Comment: If you want to close the bracket, it is probably no case distinction and you shouldn't use the `cases` environment. To enclose something between (big) delimiters use the `\left` and `\right` commands. E.g., to enclose something between braces, try `\[\left\{\begin{array}{cc}1&2\\3&4\end{array}\right\}\]` . If this doesn't solve your problem, ask a separate question and describe what you want to achieve.